# Postgres; why can not see all tables for all schema with \z

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostGIS which defines three schema (Base, layers and public)  I have tables defined in all three schemas but when I login with the commandline \z shows only those table in the public schema.

This happens if I connect with postgres or another user that actually owns the tables.  I am clearly missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\dp` or `\z` will only show tables *in the [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH)*.

If you're using multiple schemas, you may want to add them to your default `search_path` for your interactive login user (`ALTER USER ... SET search_path ...`) or in your `.psqlrc`.